# Street gang dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a [street gang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang) dataset listing with as many following fields as possible:

- gang name
- number of members
- number of crimes (ideally classified into different crime categories)
- age, gender and nationality of its members

If possible, in the US and yearly data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bureau of justice stats, but i'm not sure how detailed (to the level you want) this will be:
http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=36
not datasets but you can find stuff:
http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/ten-years-after-the-fbi-since-9-11/just-the-facts-1/violent-gang-initiatives
http://www.nationalgangcenter.gov/
possible winner:
http://www.nationalgangcenter.gov/About/Related-Web-Sites
criminal stats archive has alot too:
http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/studies?archive=NACJD&q=gang&permit[0]=AVAILABLE&x=0&y=0